# ASP .Net MVC model popup dilouge box didnt show when click on button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing a problem in my ASP.NET MVC project.

I have created a project with database first approach but when trying to open edit page using popup dialog, the dialog didn't get shown.

Tables class using auto generated table class created at the time of adding Entity Framework module.

```
namespace Ecommerce_EF_DB_18May21.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
            
    public partial class Tbl_Category
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Tbl_Category()
        {
            this.Tbl_Product = new HashSet<Tbl_Product>();
        }
            
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
        public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
            
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tbl_Product> Tbl_Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

These are my controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditP(int id)
{
    var category = categoryService.GetCategoryID(id);
    return PartialView(category);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditP(Tbl_Category category)
{
    categoryService.updateCategory(category);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Edit button to call popup dialog in Index page

```
<div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category Name</td>
                    <td>Is Active</td>
                    <td>Is Featured</td>
                    <td>Actions</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
                        <td>@item.IsActive</td>
                        <td>@item.IsFeatured</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="Btn_Edit" id="BtnEdit" data-id="@item.CategoryId" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit">Edit</button>
                    

        <button class="dltBtn" data-id="@item.CategoryId">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the Edit page markup:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditP";

    var trueChecked = Model.IsFeatured ? "checked" : string.Empty;
    var falseChecked = !Model.IsFeatured ? "checked" : string.Empty;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="EditCat">
<div class="container">
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalEdit">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Category</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@Model.CategoryId" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" value="@Model.CategoryName" class="form-control" id="txtName1" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Category" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Is Featured?</label>
                    <input name="IsFeatured" type="radio" value="True" @trueChecked /> True
                    <input name="IsFeatured" type="radio" value="False" @falseChecked /> False
                </div>
                <br />
                <label>Image</label>
                <input id="ImageURLEdit" name="ImageURL" type="hidden" />
                <input id="imageUploadEdit" name="Image" type="file" />
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img id="EditCatImage" style="height:150px; width:250px;" />

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="UpdateBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Script also attached

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <script>
     //EditBtn Modal
     $("#UpdateBtn").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Category/EditP',
             data: $("#EditCat").serialize()
         })
         .done(function (response) {
             $("#myModalEdit").html(response);
             $("#actionCon").html("");
         })
         .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Fail");
         });
     });
 
     //Image Upload
     $("#imageUpload").change(function () {
         var element = this;
         var formData = new FormData();
         var totalFiles = element.files.length;

         for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
             var file = element.files[i];
             formData.append("Photo", file);
         }
 
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Shared/UploadImage',
             dataType: 'Json',
             data: formData,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false
         })
 
        .done(function (response) {
 
            if (response.Success) {
                $("#ImageURLEdit").val(response.ImageURL);
                $("#EditCatImage").attr("src", response.ImageURL);   
            }
        })
        .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Fail");
        });
}); 
</script>
```

Now when I click on edit button no popup shows and browser shows like hang position.

After click on edit button screen shot attached.

Comment: There is no screenshot attached... is there any error in the browser console?.. You have loaded the jquery explicitly in Edit Page Markup but not bootstrap js and CSS files..

Comment: I have removed what appears to be a (your) private phone number at the end of the post. Please do not disclose unwanted private information on the internet.

Comment: it seems like your id target is not reaching your modal. u need a unique 
 id as a example : ```id="myModalEdit-@item.CategoryID"``` . i think u are just trying to make a dynamic modal. in a easy way, u can foreach that modal and give values in that foreach. in a hard way, u can create partial view and call it when u click to modal button. just let me know if u wanna do that in a hard way. i will answer for it

Comment: Hi BerkGarip, not understand your provided solution can you please provide complete example. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Akshay Gaonkar,  there is no error in browser console.

Comment: Hi BerkGarip, please help in hard way. thanks